# What lifetimes do I use to create Rust structs that reference each other cyclically?

Tags: struct, reference, circular-reference, rust

I'd like to have struct members that know their parent. This is approximately what I'm trying to do:

```
struct Parent<'me> {
    children: Vec<Child<'me>>,
}

struct Child<'me> {
    parent: &'me Parent<'me>,
    i: i32,
}

fn main() {
    let mut p = Parent { children: vec![] };
    let c1 = Child { parent: &p, i: 1 };
    p.children.push(c1);
}
```

I tried to appease the compiler with lifetimes without completely understanding what I was doing.

Here's the error message I'm stuck on:

```
error[E0502]: cannot borrow `p.children` as mutable because `p` is also borrowed as immutable
  --> src/main.rs:13:5
   |
12 |     let c1 = Child { parent: &p, i: 1 };
   |                               - immutable borrow occurs here
13 |     p.children.push(c1);
   |     ^^^^^^^^^^ mutable borrow occurs here
14 | }
   | - immutable borrow ends here
```

That makes some sense, but I'm not at all sure where to go from here.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

It is not possible to create cyclic structures with borrowed pointers.

There is not any *good* way of achieving cyclic data structures at present; the only real solutions are:

1. Use reference counting with [`Rc<T>`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/rc/struct.Rc.html) with a cyclic structure with [`Rc::new()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/rc/struct.Rc.html#method.new) and [`Rc:downgrade()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/rc/struct.Rc.html#method.downgrade). Read the [`rc` module documentation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/rc/index.html) and be careful to not create cyclic structures that use strong references, as these will cause memory leaks.
2. Use raw/unsafe pointers (`*T`).

Comment: Thanks; very good to know. I guess I'll see if I can refactor the smarts in the Child up to the Parent and get rid of the need for the parent pointer.

Comment: Actually, that idea is a small nightmare, and `*T` seems like exactly what I want. But I can't seem to use it to access the members of Parent. When I try to use `c1.parent.i` (assuming Parent has a `i:int` field, not shown in my example), I get `error: attempted access of field 'i' on type '*Parent', but no field with that name was found`. I can't find much in the way of information about these beasts.

Comment: Never mind. Rust doesn't auto-sugarize unsafe pointers, so `(*c1.parent).i` works (in an `unsafe` block).

Comment: If the child object stores `std::rc::Weak` instead of `Rc`, it should work fine without `new_unchecked`, as there will be no (strong) cyclic references.

Comment: Is this answer still valid?

Comment: @EkremDinçel: yes, and it’s extremely unlikely to ever change.