# Recursive structs error lifetime (cannot infer an appropriate lifetime for lifetime parameter in function call... [E0495])

Tags: recursion, struct, rust, lifetime

I can't figure out the lifetime parameters for this code. Everything I try usually results in a compiler error:

> consider using an explicit lifetime parameter as shown

or something like

> in type `&'ent Entity<'a, 'ent>`, reference has a longer lifetime than the data it references.

`Entity`, `Reference` are simplified versions to keep this example minimal.

```
struct Entity<'a> {
    id: i32,
    name: &'a str,
    references: Option<Vec<Reference<'a>>>,
}

struct Reference<'a> {
    entity: &'a Entity<'a>,
}

fn main() {
    let mut ents: Vec<Entity> = vec![Entity {
                                      id: 0,
                                      name: "Zero",
                                      references: None,
                                  },
                                  Entity {
                                      id: 1,
                                      name: "One",
                                      references: None,
                                  },
                                  Entity {
                                      id: 2,
                                      name: "Two",
                                      references: None,
                                  },
                                  Entity {
                                      id: 3,
                                      name: "Three",
                                      references: None,
                                  }];
    let references_ents_id = vec![vec![3, 1, 2], vec![1], vec![0, 3], vec![3, 0]];
    create_references(&references_ents_id, &mut ents);
}

fn create_references(refs_id: &Vec<Vec<i32>>, ents_vec: &mut Vec<Entity>) {
    for (id_ent, references) in refs_id.iter().enumerate() {
        let mut references_of_ent: Vec<Reference> = vec![];
        for id_ent in references {
            references_of_ent.push(Reference {
                entity: ents_vec.iter().find(|ent| ent.id == *id_ent).unwrap(),
            });
        }
        ents_vec[id_ent].references = Some(references_of_ent);
    }
}
```

[Rust Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=9f7ec1dc153c00f2c15db395215ddae1&version=stable&backtrace=0)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was looking in the wrong direction. And so, I found a solution, but unfortunately it is not safe.

- You can implement it using `Rc` and `Weak` to allow shared ownership of nodes, although this approach pays the cost of memory management.
- You can implement it using unsafe code using raw pointers. This will be more efficient, but bypasses Rust’s safety guarantees.
- Using borrowed references with `UnsafeCell`.

[Rust FAQ](https://www.rust-lang.org/en-US/faq.html#ownership)

[Other answer on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20698384/lifetime-of-rust-structs-that-reference-each-other#20704252)

Example of implementation unsafe version with raw pointers:

```
struct Entity<'a> {
    id: i32,
    name: &'a str,
    references: Option<Vec<Reference<'a>>>,
}

struct Reference<'a> {
    entity: *const Entity<'a>,
}
```

Rust Playground: https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=8237d8cb80a681c981a85610104f2e5c&version=stable&backtrace=0