# Value doesn't live long enough when put in struct

Tags: struct, rust, lifetime

I'm trying to work with LLVM in Rust using [this crate](https://github.com/TomBebb/llvm-rs). I'm trying to create a code generator struct to hold the context, module, and builder for me, but when I try to compile I get an error message that says `c does not live long enough`. How can I get this to compile, and why isn't c living long enough?

Code:

```
use llvm::*;
use llvm::Attribute::*;
pub struct CodeGen<'l> {
    context: CBox<Context>,
    builder: CSemiBox<'l, Builder>,
    module: CSemiBox<'l, Module>,
}
impl<'l> CodeGen<'l> {
    pub fn new() -> CodeGen<'l> {
        let c = Context::new();
        let b = Builder::new(&c);
        let m = Module::new("test", &c);
        CodeGen {
            context: c,
            builder: b,
            module: m,
        }
    }
}
```

Full error message:

```
error: `c` does not live long enough
  --> src/codegen.rs:17:31
   |
17 |         let b = Builder::new(&c);
   |                               ^ does not live long enough
...
24 |     }
   |     - borrowed value only lives until here
   |
note: borrowed value must be valid for the lifetime 'l as defined on the body at 15:32...
  --> src/codegen.rs:15:33
   |
15 |     pub fn new() -> CodeGen<'l> {
   |                                 ^

error: `c` does not live long enough
  --> src/codegen.rs:18:38
   |
18 |         let m = Module::new("test", &c);
   |                                      ^ does not live long enough
...
24 |     }
   |     - borrowed value only lives until here
   |
note: borrowed value must be valid for the lifetime 'l as defined on the body at 15:32...
  --> src/codegen.rs:15:33
   |
15 |     pub fn new() -> CodeGen<'l> {
   |                                 ^

error: aborting due to 2 previous errors
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like one of those situations where lifetime elision makes things less clear.

Here's the [prototype](https://tombebbington.github.io/llvm-rs/src/llvm/src/builder.rs.html#44) of `Builder::new`:

```
pub fn new(context: &Context) -> CSemiBox<Builder>
```

Which might make you think that the `CSemiBox` doesn't have any relation to the lifetime of `context`. But the [definition](https://tombebbington.github.io/llvm-rs/llvm/struct.CSemiBox.html) of `CSemiBox` has a lifetime parameter:

```
pub struct CSemiBox<'a, D>
```

As I understand it, when the output type of a function (in this case `Builder::new`) has a lifetime parameter, it can be elided if there is only one input lifetime. (The lifetime elision rules are described in [the book](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/lifetimes.html#lifetime-elision) and in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40325690/lifetime-elision).) In this case, the output lifetime is taken to be the same as the input lifetime. That means the prototype from before is actually equivalent to the following:

```
pub fn new<'a>(context: &'a Context) -> CSemiBox<'a, Builder>
```

I hope this clarifies what's happening: after `Builder::new(&c)`, the `CSemiBox` contains a reference to the `Context` it was created from (`b` contains a reference to `c`). You can't put `b` and `c` in the same struct because the compiler has to be able to prove that `c` outlives `b`. For a more thorough explanation, see [Why can't I store a value and a reference to that value in the same struct?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32300132/why-cant-i-store-a-value-and-a-reference-to-that-value-in-the-same-struct)

There are two ways I can think of to handle this. (You can't use `Rc` because you don't control the crate.)

1. Don't store the `Context` inside the `CodeGen` struct. You're limited in how you can structure your code, but that's not necessarily bad.
2. Since the `Context` is stored on the heap, you can use `unsafe` to make the references (appear to) have a `'static` lifetime. Something like the following snippet ought to work, which removes the lifetime annotation from `CodeGen`. If you do this (as any time you use `unsafe`), **you take responsibility for ensuring the safety of the exposed interface**. That means, for example, `CodeGen` can't hand out references to `builder` and `module`, because that could leak a `'static` reference to `context`.

   ```
   pub struct CodeGen {
       context: CBox<Context>,
       builder: CSemiBox<'static, Builder>,
       module: CSemiBox<'static, Module>,
   }
   impl CodeGen {
       pub fn new() -> CodeGen {
           let c = Context::new();  // returns a CBox<Context>
           let c_static_ref: &'static _ = unsafe {
               let c_ptr = c.as_ptr() as *const _;  // get the underlying heap pointer
               &*c_ptr
           };
           let b = Builder::new(c_static_ref);
           let m = Module::new("test", c_static_ref);
           CodeGen {
               context: c,
               builder: b,
               module: m,
           }
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: @FrancisGagné AHA! That's the one I wanted to link to but I could only find [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20698384/lifetime-of-rust-structs-that-reference-each-other) by searching. Thanks

Comment: Thank you for the great answer!

Comment: I think that I will just not use a struct and have the calling code create the context, module, and builder and then pass them in to the code generator function.

Comment: @trentcl do you this is this a duplicate of either http://stackoverflow.com/q/32300132/234590 or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20698384/lifetime-of-rust-structs-that-reference-each-other?

Comment: @Shepmaster Actually, I think the key to this answer was realizing that an `'a` had been elided. But I guess I did go into a bit more detail and some of it is redundant